# How to use namespaced attributes with OPENXML?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm trying to use [T-SQL's `OPENXML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx) function to parse XML into tabular form, but I keep  getting misleading errors in presence of namespaced attributes.

For instance, SQL Server claims the following about this well-formed XML document:

```
DECLARE @hdoc int;
DECLARE @doc varchar(1000);

SET @doc =
'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Data xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2016-06-13">
    <Record userId="123456" username="jeffp" termId="129" dmd:surveyId="1234567">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="AACSBSUFF" entryKey="Participating" text="Participating"/>
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="DEPARTMENT" entryKey="WCBD" text="WCBD"/>
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="QUALIFICATION" entryKey="Instructional Practitioner" text="Instructional Practitioner"/>
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="RANK" entryKey="Academic Staff" text="Academic Staff"/>
        <GENSERVE id="33426841601" dmd:lastModified="2011-03-15T10:23:01" dmd:startDate="2010-07-01">
            <TYPE>University</TYPE>
            <TYPEOTHER/>
            <ORG>University Academic Advising Council   </ORG>
            <ROLE>Committee Member</ROLE>
            <ROLEOTHER/>
            <OFFICE>President/Elect/Past</OFFICE>
            <RESPONSIBILITIES/>
            <NUMHOURS/>
            <ELECAPP>Elected</ELECAPP>
            <AUDIENCE>Local</AUDIENCE>
            <EXOFFICIO/>
            <DTM_START>July</DTM_START>
            <DTD_START/>
            <DTY_START>2010</DTY_START>
            <START_START>2010-07-01</START_START>
            <START_END>2010-07-31</START_END>
            <DTM_END/>
            <DTD_END/>
            <DTY_END/>
            <END_START></END_START>
            <END_END></END_END>
        </GENSERVE>
    </Record>
</Data>
';

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @doc;

SELECT    *
FROM       OPENXML (@hdoc, '/Data/Record/GENSERVE', 2)
           with(TYPE varchar(250),
                ORG varchar(250)  )

exec sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc;
```

> ```
> The XML parse error 0xc00ce55e occurred on line number 20, near the XML text "            <AUDIEN".
> The error description is 'Element was not closed.'.
> ```

Well that's just ridiculous because if I simply delete these lines:

```
    <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="AACSBSUFF" entryKey="Participating" text="Participating"/>
    <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="DEPARTMENT" entryKey="WCBD" text="WCBD"/>
    <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="QUALIFICATION" entryKey="Instructional Practitioner" text="Instructional Practitioner"/>
    <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="RANK" entryKey="Academic Staff" text="Academic Staff"/>
```

Then I get no errors - but no data either - just empty columns.

Only if I go  through and delete *every* reference to any namespace, then it'll work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Record userId="123456" username="jeffp" termId="129">
        <GENSERVE id="33426841601" >
            <TYPE>University</TYPE>
            <TYPEOTHER/>
            <ORG>University Academic Advising Council   </ORG>
            <ROLE>Committee Member</ROLE>
            <ROLEOTHER/>
            <OFFICE>President/Elect/Past</OFFICE>
            <RESPONSIBILITIES/>
            <NUMHOURS/>
            <ELECAPP>Elected</ELECAPP>
            <AUDIENCE>Local</AUDIENCE>
            <EXOFFICIO/>
            <DTM_START>July</DTM_START>
            <DTD_START/>
            <DTY_START>2010</DTY_START>
            <START_START>2010-07-01</START_START>
            <START_END>2010-07-31</START_END>
            <DTM_END/>
            <DTD_END/>
            <DTY_END/>
            <END_START></END_START>
            <END_END></END_END>
        </GENSERVE>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

> ```
> TYPE          ORG
> University    University Academic Advising Council
> ```

How can I also read in the namespaced attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML string is truncated because its length is more than `varchar(1000)`, hence the XML parsing error. The error message has nothing to do with namespace.

Now come the namespace problem.. Notice that your XML has *default namespace* (namespace declared without prefix). All elements involved in your query inherit default namespace from `Data` element implicitly. You need to map a prefix to the default namespace URI, and use that prefix to reference elements in the namespace in your OPENXML query :

```
DECLARE @doc varchar(5000);

.....

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, 
     @doc, 
    '<Data xmlns:d="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" />';

SELECT    *
FROM       OPENXML (@hdoc, '/d:Data/d:Record/d:GENSERVE', 2)
           with(TYPE varchar(250) 'd:TYPE',
                ORG varchar(250) 'd:ORG' )
```

If available in your SQL Server version, you might want to consider using SQL Server's XQuery and XML data type :

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 'your xml string here'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data' )
SELECT 
    t.c.value('TYPE[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' )  AS TYPE,
    t.c.value( 'ORG[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' ) AS ORG
FROM @xml.nodes('/Data/Record/GENSERVE') t(c)
```

Comment: Oh awesome, thanks, that makes so much sense I feel dumb! I am excited to try it when I get back to work, thanks!

Comment: thanks again for not only fixing my dumb problem and answering my question, but most of all I appreciate your improved solution *"using SQL Server's XQuery and XML data type"* which was something I was completely unaware of. way to solve [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/321521)!